# Generic Template Image Does not Appear in App Messenger Bot

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am loading image for the generic template  from my database, the image is shown in web version of messenger but is not loaded in the Android App.

I am loading the image from my site hosted on app engine and the site has a SSL certificate

Comment: Have the same issue ... any fix you got?

Comment: @ifti I was serving image via a Blob, Messenger App is not able to fetch it via the blob url. If you are using App Engine use Cloud Storage to serve your images